# Countdown mechanic solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list that incorporates many stages, 13 to be precise. These stages include actions and all the actions have a target date field and an actual date field. My users require that a 16 week countdown between stage 6 and 9 begin once the first action in stage 6 has a date added to the target date field. I believe ultimately that they will want a date 16 weeks in the future automatically calculated so they can see at a glance the date 16 weeks from the point of this action being populated.
I would like to present them with a countdown in days and future date. I'm assuming a workflow would fit the brief but how would I configure the workflow?
I only have access to SPD 2010.
Regards

Comment: Where do you want the countdown displayed? Only in a View, on the DisplayForm as well? In 2013 both ca  be done with CSR/JSlink. Are you allowed to add stuff to the MasterPage in your SP2010?

Comment: I can do anything I want in the environment, I was thinking a view would be easiest.

Comment: I found this that calculates the difference between 2 date fields. It seems to work so long as the list item is updated regularly I have a WF that can do that: =DATEDIF([start Date],[Open Date]-(MOD([Start Date],1)>MOD([Open Date],1)),"d")&" days, "&TEXT(MOD([Open Date]-[Start Date],1),"hh "" hrs, "" mm "" mins""")

Comment: Yes, Calculated Column Formulas are only updated when the List Item is updated. If you are updating the item every day with a WF you might even use the (normally wrongly calculating) Today() function in a Formula

Comment: Danny could you explain the Today() method please?

Comment: You can use the Formula:  Today()-Created  to get the number of days past; provided you update the List Item every day, which is what you do with workflow. If you do not update the listitem, Today() will result to the last time the item was updated.